# Number of remaining days of a month after maximum value appear

Tags: r

I have a panel data frame like this

```
date    firms return
5/1/1988    A   5
6/1/1988    A   6
7/1/1988    A   4
8/1/1988    A   5
9/1/1988    A   6
11/1/1988   A   6
12/1/1988   A   13
13/01/1988  A   3
14/01/1988  A   2
15/01/1988  A   5
16/01/1988  A   2
18/01/1988  A   7
19/01/1988  A   3
20/01/1988  A   5
21/01/1988  A   7
22/01/1988  A   5
23/01/1988  A   9
25/01/1988  A   1
26/01/1988  A   5
27/01/1988  A   2
28/01/1988  A   7
29/01/1988  A   2
5/1/1988    B   5
6/1/1988    B   7
7/1/1988    B   5
8/1/1988    B   9
9/1/1988    B   1
11/1/1988   B   5
12/1/1988   B   2
13/01/1988  B   7
14/01/1988  B   2
15/01/1988  B   5
16/01/1988  B   6
18/01/1988  B   8
19/01/1988  B   5
20/01/1988  B   4
21/01/1988  B   3
22/01/1988  B   18
23/01/1988  B   5
25/01/1988  B   2
26/01/1988  B   7
27/01/1988  B   3
28/01/1988  B   9
29/01/1988  B   2
```

Now from the above panel data, I want to find a variable called DMAX. DMAX means the unit of days as the difference between the Maximum return day and the last trading day of the same month. For example, in January 1988 the Maximum return appears on  12 Jan 1988 for firm A. Hence the DMAX is the number of days between 12 Jan 1988 to the end of that month which is 15 days. 
For firm B, the maximum value appears on 22 Jan 1988. So the remaining number of days of that month is 6 days. Therefore the expected outcome is

```
date    Firms   DMAX(days)
Jan-88    A      15
Jan-88    B      6
```

I would be grateful if you can help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) Base R** For each year/month and firm aggregate the difference between the number of rows and the position of the maximum return row.  No packages are used.

```
with(transform(DF, date = as.Date(date, "%d/%m/%Y")), 
  aggregate(list(DMAX = return), 
    data.frame(date = format(date, "%Y-%m"), firms),
    function(x) length(x) - which.max(x)))
```

giving:

```
     date firms DMAX
1 1988-01     A   15
2 1988-01     B    6
```

**2) zoo**  Read `DF` into a zoo object `zd` with one column per firm and then aggregate that by year/month. Finally melt it to a long form data frame using `fortify.zoo`.  The `fortify.zoo` line can be omitted if a zoo time series object is ok as the result.

```
library(zoo)

zd <- read.zoo(DF, index = "date", format = "%d/%m/%Y", split = "firms")
ag <- aggregate(zd, as.yearmon, function(x) length(na.omit(x)) - which.max(na.omit(x)))
fortify.zoo(ag, melt = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
     Index Series Value
1 Jan 1988      A    15
2 Jan 1988      B     6
```

Note that `ag` is a monthly zoo series of the form:

```
> ag
          A B
Jan 1988 15 6
```

**3) data.table**

```
library(data.table)

DT <- as.data.table(DF)
DT[, list(DMAX = .N - which.max(return)), 
       by = list(date = format(as.Date(date, "%d/%m/%Y"), "%Y-%m"), firms)]
```

giving:

```
      date firms DMAX
1: 1988-01     A   15
2: 1988-01     B    6
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
date    firms return
5/1/1988    A   5
6/1/1988    A   6
7/1/1988    A   4
8/1/1988    A   5
9/1/1988    A   6
11/1/1988   A   6
12/1/1988   A   13
13/01/1988  A   3
14/01/1988  A   2
15/01/1988  A   5
16/01/1988  A   2
18/01/1988  A   7
19/01/1988  A   3
20/01/1988  A   5
21/01/1988  A   7
22/01/1988  A   5
23/01/1988  A   9
25/01/1988  A   1
26/01/1988  A   5
27/01/1988  A   2
28/01/1988  A   7
29/01/1988  A   2
5/1/1988    B   5
6/1/1988    B   7
7/1/1988    B   5
8/1/1988    B   9
9/1/1988    B   1
11/1/1988   B   5
12/1/1988   B   2
13/01/1988  B   7
14/01/1988  B   2
15/01/1988  B   5
16/01/1988  B   6
18/01/1988  B   8
19/01/1988  B   5
20/01/1988  B   4
21/01/1988  B   3
22/01/1988  B   18
23/01/1988  B   5
25/01/1988  B   2
26/01/1988  B   7
27/01/1988  B   3
28/01/1988  B   9
29/01/1988  B   2
"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using the dplyr package would be the following. I called your data mydf. First, manipulate `date`. Then, group the data by `date` and `firms`. Then, you look for the row with the largest value in `return` and handle subtraction.

```
mutate(mydf, date = format(as.Date(date, format = "%d/%m/%Y"), "%m-%Y")) %>%
group_by(date, firms) %>%
summarize(DMAX = n() - which.max(return))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   date [?]
#  date    firms  DMAX
#  <chr>   <fct> <int>
#1 01-1988 A        15
#2 01-1988 B         6
```

DATA

```
mydf <-structure(list(date = structure(c(18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L), .Label = c("11/1/1988", 
"12/1/1988", "13/01/1988", "14/01/1988", "15/01/1988", "16/01/1988", 
"18/01/1988", "19/01/1988", "20/01/1988", "21/01/1988", "22/01/1988", 
"23/01/1988", "25/01/1988", "26/01/1988", "27/01/1988", "28/01/1988", 
"29/01/1988", "5/1/1988", "6/1/1988", "7/1/1988", "8/1/1988", 
"9/1/1988"), class = "factor"), firms = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), 
return = c(5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 13L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 
3L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 9L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 9L, 1L, 
5L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 18L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 
3L, 9L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -44L
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

df1 %>%
  mutate(date = dmy(date),
         month = as.yearmon(date)) %>%
  group_by(firms, month) %>%
  summarise(i = which(return == max(return)),
            DMAX = last(date) - date[last(i)]) %>%
  select(month, firms, DMAX)
## A tibble: 2 x 3
## Groups:   firms [2]
#  month         firms DMAX     
#  <S3: yearmon> <chr> <time>   
#1 Jan 1988      A     17 days  
#2 Jan 1988      B     " 7 days"
```